# JPopupMenu gets closed as soon as the mouse enters in an embedded JCheckboxMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu, multipleselection

I wrote the following code to have a JPopupMenu that allows multiple selection of different items.
The problem is that, as soon as the mouse enters one of the displayed JCheckboxMenuItems, the JPopupMenu gets closed. This issue doesn't occur if I replace JCheckboxMenuItem with, for example, JLabel but, for sure, JLabel doesn't work for my purpose.
Any idea of what could trigger this issue? Any idea of how this problem can be resolved in a better way? I apologize for the newbie question but I'm not a java developer. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedborder(),"Select Layers");
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
for (MyAction layer : layers) {
    JCheckBoxMenuItem box = new JCheckBoxMenuItem(layer);
    box.setIcon(new SquareIcon(myColor));
    panel.add(box);
}

JPopup popup = new JidePopup();
popup.add(panel)

JButton button = new JButton("Layers");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        popup.show(button,0,button.getHeight())
    }
});
```

Comment: What does MyAction do ?

Comment: no idea without your SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: is there reason to use JPanel, because BasicsPopup..., has BoxLayout in API by default, otherwise to use JWindow (reuse only one, HIDE_ON_CLOSE, playing with setVisible( true / false), wrapped into invokeLater)

Comment: @Berger MyAction is a class that extends AbstractAction and simply overrides the actionPerformed() method associated to each JCheckboxMenuItem in addition to setting its label.

Comment: @mKorbel I tried without using the JPanel and it works but multiple selection is not allowed: every time I select/unselect a menu item the popup gets closed.

Comment: @Roberto : Sure, but what does exactly the action associated with the menu items do ?

Comment: @Berger it simply shows/hides the objects linked to the menu item. But I don't think the problem lies in the action because the popup gets closed before calling the action, i.e. simply moving mouse cursor over a menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats in the nature of `JPopupMenus`. They disappear when the invoker component loses the focus. But I found a little trick [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1518459).
Create your own class and extend it from `JPopupMenu`. Then override the `setVisible` method that it will only forward `true` to the super class and create an own method that will `setVisible` of the super class to false.

```
public class StayOpenPopup extends JPopupMenu{
    public void setVisible(boolean visible){
        if(visible == true)
            super.setVisible(visible);
    }

    public void disappear() {
        super.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Then use it like this in your code

```
[...]
StayOpenPopup popup = new StayOpenPopup();
popup.add(panel);
[...]
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if(popup.isVisible())
            popup.disappear();
        else popup.show(button,0,button.getHeight());
    }
});
```

Now one click on button will show it. And it will stay visible until next click on Button.